# Rename JSON fields with circe

Tags: json, scala, circe

I want to have different names of fields in my case classes and in my JSON, therefore I need a comfortable way of renaming in both, encoding and decoding.

Does someone have a good solution ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Custom key mappings via annotations](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/custom-codecs.html#custom-key-mappings-via-annotations). The most generic way is the `JsonKey` annotation from `io.circe.generic.extras._`. Example from the docs:

```scala
import io.circe.generic.extras._, io.circe.syntax._

implicit val config: Configuration = Configuration.default

@ConfiguredJsonCodec case class Bar(@JsonKey("my-int") i: Int, s: String)

Bar(13, "Qux").asJson
// res5: io.circe.Json = JObject(object[my-int -> 13,s -> "Qux"])
```

This requires the package `circe-generic-extras`.

Comment: Please note that you'll not be allowed to declare `implicit` values at the top level as mentioned in the answered. However, you can add to the bottom something like this:

```object Bar {
  implicit val config: Configuration = Configuration.default
}```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a code sample for Decoder (bit verbose since it won't remove the old field):

```
  val pimpedDecoder = deriveDecoder[PimpClass].prepare {
    _.withFocus {
      _.mapObject { x =>
        val value = x("old-field")
        value.map(x.add("new-field", _)).getOrElse(x)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
implicit val decodeFieldType: Decoder[FieldType] =
  Decoder.forProduct5("nth", "isVLEncoded", "isSerialized", "isSigningField", "type")
                     (FieldType.apply)
```

This is a simple way if you have lots of different field names.
https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/custom-codecs.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mapJson` function on Encoder to derive an encoder from the generic one and remap your field name.

And you can use the `prepare` function on Decoder to transform the JSON passed to a generic Decoder.

You could also write both from scratch, but it may be a ton of boilerplate, those solutions should both be a handful of lines max each.

Comment: Where can I find more examples of using Circe to do JSON schema evolution? e.g. a new field in Scala model but not in JSON, a removed field in Scala model but in JSON, a renamed field, etc.

Comment: I think the official documentation  is quite nice : https://circe.github.io/circe/

Comment: When evolution getting harder we prefer to split case classes to common model an versions of JSON representation. For transformation between them we use Chimney's macros: https://github.com/scalalandio/chimney It is much easy and safer way than writing and support of custom codecs.

Answer (score 1):

The following function can be used to rename a circe's JSON field:

```scala
import io.circe._

object CirceUtil {
  def renameField(json: Json, fieldToRename: String, newName: String): Json =
    (for {
      value <- json.hcursor.downField(fieldToRename).focus
      newJson <- json.mapObject(_.add(newName, value)).hcursor.downField(fieldToRename).delete.top
    } yield newJson).getOrElse(json)
}
```

You can use it in an `Encoder` like so:

```scala
implicit val circeEncoder: Encoder[YourCaseClass] = deriveEncoder[YourCaseClass].mapJson(
  CirceUtil.renameField(_, "old_field_name", "new_field_name")
)
```

### Extra

**Unit tests**

```scala
import io.circe.parser._
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

class CirceUtilSpec extends Specification {

  "CirceUtil" should {
    "renameField" should {
      "correctly rename field" in {
        val json = parse("""{ "oldFieldName": 1 }""").toOption.get
        val resultJson = CirceUtil.renameField(json, "oldFieldName", "newFieldName")
        resultJson.hcursor.downField("oldFieldName").focus must beNone
        resultJson.hcursor.downField("newFieldName").focus must beSome
      }

      "return unchanged json if field is not found" in {
        val json = parse("""{ "oldFieldName": 1 }""").toOption.get
        val resultJson = CirceUtil.renameField(json, "nonExistentField", "newFieldName")
        resultJson must be equalTo json
      }
    }
  }
}
```